# Return the number of new users by month

Tags: sql

Table **ORDERS** contains the following columns
order_id, order_date, ship_date, ship_mode, customer_id, country, quantity

I just need the code. Here is my work.

```
SELECT order_date, COUNT (Customer_Id) As new_usercount
FROM (
    SELECT Customer_Id, DATE(MIN(Order_Date)) AS order_date
    FROM Orders
    GROUP BY Customer_Id
) AS ch
GROUP BY order_date
```

Thanks

Comment: How are you determining who is a "new user"?  If the first order is in the current month and year?

Comment: You should provide with some sample data, and the result you're getting along with the expected result. See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is almost correct.
After you aggregate to get each customer's min order date you must group by the year and month of the dates and not the dates:

```
SELECT YEAR(order_date) year, 
       MONTH(order_date) month, 
       COUNT(*) new_usercount 
FROM ( 
  SELECT Customer_Id, MIN(Order_Date) order_date 
  FROM Orders 
  GROUP BY Customer_Id 
) t 
GROUP BY YEAR(order_date), MONTH(order_date)
```

Comment: Thanks! Just to be 100%: I do not need to put new_usercount with AS? Also, what is the function of the "t" after the ")"  Appreciate!

Comment: `AS` is optional. `t` is the alias of the subquery. I assumed by your code that you are using MySql and in MySql all subqueries must be aliased.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much forpas. Kind regards,